# How can i make a text fit in a button regardless of the user font size?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, expo

I have a button with a title that fits perfectly in my phone, but I received some issues from other people with bigger font sizes, where the text gets cropped because the button background is too small.

I thought this was because I used width and height with literals, so I changed it to percentages, but the error persists.
How can I adjust the button size to hold the text properly on any device?

This is my button

```
button: {
  backgroundColor: blue,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  padding: 9,
  borderRadius: 5,
  marginTop: 10,
  width: '40%',
  height: '10%',
},
```

and this is how i use it

```
<View style={styles.button}>
  <Ionicons.Button
    name="alarm"
    size={20}
    color="white"
    onPress={showTimepicker}
    backgroundColor={'transparent'}>
    <Text style={styles.notifsText}>Definir horario de Notificaciones</Text>
  </Ionicons.Button>
</View>
```

This is how it looks on my phone
[image: my phone]

This is how it looks on my friend`s phone
[image: my friends phone]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<Text allowFontScaling={false}>example </Text>
```

Comment: Well, its not what i wanted but i guess it kinda solves the problem, but some people may have trouble reading it.

Answer (score 0):

`width` and `height` as percentages refer to a percentage of the inherited **parent** size, so the button will remain the same size, respective of the parent not changing its size. Try removing these attributes to allow the button to take on its full available size.

Comment: width and height of the view parent of the button werent present, so i added width : '100%' and height:'100%', but that does not solve my problem, if i want the button to be the 100% of the screen i can do it, but i want the text to fit in all devices without the button being giant for users with smaller fonts.

Comment: You can see that my font size is the smallest possible in android, and my friends is a little bigger, so in my screen the button holds the whole text but in his doesnt.

Comment: This answers your's own question. You have given height to the button which will be the same across all devices but the font size changes w.r.t screen size. You should try removing the height.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because default value of allowFontScaling is true thats why its keeps different on different phone.You can pass `allowFontScaling={false}` as a prop to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `vw` or `vh` as units for font size. With some calculations you'll get an appropriate solution.